# Multiple find-and-replaces, recursively

Tags: bash, text, replace, substitution

I'm looking for an efficient way to perform a large (say 100) number of find-and-replace operations across multiple files. By find-and-replace, I mean a simple substitution (e.g. in sed or vim syntax, that would s/cow/pig AND s/fish/bird AND s/cat/dog ... all of these, for all matched files).

Maybe sed is the best choice, but I want to leave it open-ended as I suspect there could be more efficient solutions.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little vague and there would be many ways to do it. For multiple substitution across several files, you can use `sed` in loop.

The following approach would require two set of files. Files containing words that needs to be substituted and a file containing their replacement in order.

You can read the file and perform `sed` operation. Something like this:

```
while read -r substitute && read -r replacement <&3; do
  sed -i "s/ "$substitute" / "$replacement" /g" *.txt
done <substitute.text 3<replacement.text
```

Notice the `*.txt` thats a `glob` to pass multiple files. Also, there is `-i` option passed to `sed` which does in-file substitution. I wouldn't recommend it if you are toying with different approaches. You can use `-i"bak"` to make backups of original files.

Like I said earlier, this is just a suggestion to get the ball rolling.

Comment: Thanks. If the question's vague, it's because I'm looking for the most efficient solution, as it can lead to order-of-magnitude improvements, ie hours to minutes.

Comment: @mahemoff Sure, I agree. :)